# client must wait until service callback finish?

Tags: ros, rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As title, I have the following two python codes,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import rospy
from test_srv.srv import *

def client_send(x, y):
    rospy.wait_for_service('test_server')
    try:

        t1 = rospy.get_time()
        c = rospy.ServiceProxy('test_server', test)
        c(x, y)
        print("Run Time: ", (rospy.get_time() - t1))
        

    except rospy.ServiceException as e:
        print("Service call failed: %s"%e)

def do_something():
    
    print("Doing something...")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    rospy.init_node('test_server_node_1')

    x = 10
    y = 11

    print("Client: Start sending.")
    client_send(x, y)
    do_something()
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
from time import sleep
from test_srv.srv import test, testResponse
import rospy

def handleCB(req):
    print("start sleep")
    sleep(3)
    print("Get request: %s and %s" %(req.a, req.b))
    return testResponse()


def test_server():
    rospy.init_node('test_server_node')
    s = rospy.Service('test_server',test, handleCB)
    print("Ready.")
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_server()
```

the srv file:

```
int64 a
int64 b
---
```

When running these codes, the client will keep waiting until server finishes its `handleCB` function.

My question is that can client send request and then do other things, not just wait for the server sending response back?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402138/client-must-wait-until-service-callback-finish?/) by [RyanChen.YLC](https://answers.ros.org/users/99089/ryanchen.ylc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 44 on 2022-06-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RyanChen.YLC](https://answers.ros.org/users/99089/ryanchen.ylc/) on 2022-06-10**:
Update:

running result: [see image](https://imgur.com/rdLd4uq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Services are synchronous, therefore your client will wait for an answer before resuming execution.
Topics are asynchronous, which means you can send a request and the client can continue the execution. To get a similar behaviour to a service but async, you'll need one topic to send the request and one topic to listen for an answer.

---

Originally posted by [Alex-SSoM](https://answers.ros.org/users/86099/alex-ssom/) with karma: 163 on 2022-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-06-10**:
RyanChen: rather than make up your own protocol, you could look at http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib, which is one approach to do what you want. Notice that SimpleActionClient and SimpleActionServer have limitations (to keep them "simple").